# RuntimeError: File loading is not yet supported on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, runtime-error, mediapipe

i have been working on a hand gesture recognition model, i have been updating, downgrading and debugging a lot of modules and then this error showed up:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_addons\utils\tfa_eol_msg.py", line 23
    warnings.warn(
UserWarning: 

TensorFlow Addons (TFA) has ended development and introduction of new features.
TFA has entered a minimal maintenance and release mode until a planned end of life in May 2024.
Please modify downstream libraries to take dependencies from other repositories in our TensorFlow community (e.g. Keras, Keras-CV, and Keras-NLP). 

For more information see: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2807 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\project1.py", line 27, in <module>
    data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe_model_maker\python\vision\gesture_recognizer\dataset.py", line 202, in from_folder
    hand_data = _get_hand_data(
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe_model_maker\python\vision\gesture_recognizer\dataset.py", line 114, in _get_hand_data
    with _HandLandmarker.create_from_options(
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\vision\hand_landmarker.py", line 271, in create_from_options
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\vision\core\base_vision_task_api.py", line 65, in __init__
    self._runner = TaskRunner.create(graph_config, packet_callback)
RuntimeError: File loading is not yet supported on Windows
```

mediapipe model maker 0.1.0.2
tensorflow 2.14.0
python 3.10.0

this is my original code (only the problematic part):

```
from mediapipe_model_maker.python.vision import gesture_recognizer

data = gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder(
    dirname=IMAGES_PATH,
    hparams=gesture_recognizer.HandDataPreprocessingParams()
)

# Split the archive into training, validation and test dataset.
train_data, rest_data = data.split(0.8)
validation_data, test_data = rest_data.split(0.5)

# Train the model
hparams = gesture_recognizer.HParams(export_dir="rock_paper_scissors_model")
options = gesture_recognizer.GestureRecognizerOptions(hparams=hparams)
model = gesture_recognizer.GestureRecognizer.create(
    train_data=train_data,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    options=options
)
print("done")

# Load the rock-paper-scissor image archive.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use anacoda create environment with python 3.8.18
[image]

After done, open terminal type

```
conda activate [Your_Environment_That_Created_Name]
```

You will see environment name before prompt

```
(Your_Environment_That_Created_Name) E:\donghang\reader_multi\train_hand_gesture>
```

Type install mediapipe_model_maker

```
pip install mediapipe_model_maker
```

[image]